# How to use Kinect for XBOX ONE (a.k.a Kinect v2) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, software-installation, amd-graphics, opencv, kinect

I have installed OpenCV on my freshly re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 following [this blog](https://milq.github.io/install-opencv-ubuntu-debian/) and hopefully everything is just fine. Now I am going to use Kinect v2 and have searched the Web on how to install necessary software/packages. As it turns out, there are different ways to do so and I am not sure which way to choose since they may cause unexpected errors. Given the information of my computer below:

HP Envy 15 Notebook;

Processor - AMD A10-5750M with Radeon HD Graphics x 4;

Graphics - Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA (DRM 2.43.0/4.4.0-66-generic, LLVM 3.8.0);

OS - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 64-bit.

Can someone help me install all necessary ***packages/dependencies*** or ***software*** so that I can properly connect the Kinect v2 device to my laptop and use it **with OpenCV in python** environment?